# backbone destroy doesn't send a DELETE HTTP

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model, destroy, http-delete

When a create my model I don't have an id that's a reason my function destroy doesn't work, can you pleas help me

I have an another id, who is clientId:

Function to save the model:

```
 save : function (){      
              var result =this.model.save({
                    ClientId: this.$('.clientId-field').val(),
                   companyName: this.$('.companyName-field').val()
                   } ,
   delete: function() {

   this.model.destroy();
    return false;
}
```

my object :

```
0: {ClientId:1, companyName:nom compagnie,…}
   companyName: "nom compagnie"
```

please help me

```
child {collection: child, _deferProcessing: false, _listenerId: "l4", _events: Object, _queue: Backbone.BlockingQueue…}
_attributeChangeFired: false
_changing: false
_deferProcessing: false
_events: Object
_isInitialized: true
_listenerId: "l4"
_pending: false
_permitsUsed: 0
_previousAttributes: Object
_queue: Backbone.BlockingQueue
_relations: Object
attributes: Object
changed: Object
cid: "c5"
collection: child
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use different unique key expect than `id`. then you may set a Model's `idAttribute` to transparently map from that key to id.

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

   urlRoot : "/data/delete",   //root delete url 

   idAttribute: "clientId"
});

var myModel = new MyModel({
   clientId : "123"
});

myModel.destroy();
```

On call of `destroy` method, `DELETE` request will be send to URL `DELETE` `/data/delete/123`

Answer (score 0):

when i did this, my function this.model.save send a PUT HTTP and not a POST HTTP

```
   var ClientModel = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    idAttribute: "ClientId",
    validation : {
         companyName : {
               required: true,
               msg: 'companyName is required.'
}
 });
  return ClientModel;

 });
```

You must know, i generate my id before calling my function this.model.save

```
save : function (){ 
           var clientId= this.random ();
          var result =this.model.save({
                ClientId: clientId,
               companyName: this.$('.companyName-field').val()
               } ,
 delete: function() {

 this.model.destroy();
   return false;
    }
```